# Blender Python select stored object without name

Tags: python

I would like to create several cameras, and store them as follows:

```
a = bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
b = bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
c = bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
```

This command allows me to select the camera called "Camera.001"

```
bpy.data.objects['Camera.001'].select = True
```

But if my scene already contained several cameras before I created a, b & c, how would I select camera b without knowing its name?  This code doesn't work:

```
bpy.data.objects[b].select = True
```

Thanks for your help.  My python knowledge is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.ops` don't return items like that.

Instead, you want to work on the cameras and objects data blocks directly, like so:

```
camdata = bpy.data.cameras.new(name="Camera A")
a = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Camera A", object_data=camdata)
```

Then, link it to the currently active scene:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(a)
```

You could then select the camera either, by just doing:

```
a.select = True
```

or by doing

```
bpy.data.objects[a.name].select = True
```